# Rails hidden_field not work! and I use carrierwave gem for video upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My flow of of controller's actions is `new -> confirm -> create`

The video file uploaded from new can be played in confirm.
However, confirm will cause the value of nil to be set when you perform save of create.

Conversely, if you create a video after uploading it in confirm, save will work normally.

I think this problem happens because of hidden_field.
I think this problem occurs because hidden_field does not store the value properly (but the console passes the video value as a parameter)

confirm.html.erb

```
<% if @propertys.video? %>
        <td><%= video_tag @propertys.video.url, autoplay: true, muted: true, controls: true , :size => "350x260"%></td>
        <%= f.hidden_field :video, :value => @propertys.video %>
<% else %>
        <td>abc</td>
<% end %>  


new.html.erb
<td><%= f.label :内部ビデオ %></td>
<td><%= f.file_field :video, :multiple => false %></td>
```

Parameter values ​​can be checked in console
However, if you actually put it in the Strong parameter, it changes to nil.

Confirm the video in normal operation

**Edit:** controller code

```
   def confirm
    puts("======= confirm　侵入=======")
    @propertys = Property.new(property_params)
    #@property.video = params[:property][:video]
    p @propertys
  end



 def create
    puts("======= create ========")
    @propertys = Property.new(property_params)
    @propertys.user_id = current_user.id
    p @propertys
    p params[:property][:video]
    puts("＄＄＄＄＄＄＄＄  create save＄＄＄＄＄＄＄＄")
    #@property.video = params[:property][:video]
    if @propertys.save
      puts("good")
      redirect_to list_propertys_path
    else
      puts("bad")
      logger.debug @propertys.errors.inspect
      redirect_to new_property_path
    end
  end

 def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit({image: []}, :video, :image_cache, :name, :rent, :subsidy, :reward, :region, :area, :extent, :longitude, :latitude)
  end
```

videouploader.rb

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Video
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(ogg ogv 3gp mp4 m4v webm mov m2v 3g2)
  end


end
```

Comment: Hey songsugeun,

if you inspect the hidden field in your browser's developer tools, what do you see there?
My guess is that there's something like `"#<Video:0x00007f98a695a790>"` in it because `video` is an object but a hidden field can only contain a string. Therefore the video object will be converted to a string, but not in a way that does what you want.

At least that's my guess. :)

Comment: Can we see the controllers? I think your best bet is probably to save the video and create a record with a `pending` flag, then change that flag on confirmation; but I’d like to see your approach so far.

Comment: thank you for the reply.
i update  my controller code and Strong parameter code ..!

Comment: Thank you for your reply kaikuchn.
Files uploaded from new will play well in confirm, so I do not think there is a problem with the Strong parameter.
The code that clicks on a video that is playing in the Developer Tools.
<video autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" controls="controls" width="350" height="260" src="/uploads/tmp/1547199641-2677-0018-2279/SongSugeun.mp4"></video>

Answer (score 0):

With the help of others I solved it.
Thank you.
This link is for me.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-%22Upload%22-from-a-local-file

```
 @propertys.video = Rails.root.join("public/#{params[:property][:video]}").open
```